# Codeigniter: How to load Controller function in view file used in shortcode

Tags: php

Please help 
in View I want to call controller function
Beacuse I have to use this in short code

> In controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->Front = & get_instance();
}
public function view() {
    $this->index();
    $this->load->view(view');
}
```

> In view

```
<?=$this->Front->view();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var site_url = "<?php echo base_url('/controller'); ?>";
            $("#season").load(site_url);
        });
    </script>
<div id="season"> </div>
```

> Try this might help you .

Comment: Thank you  @ghugu